# jQuery math & variables

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take a variable (the value of a text input) and do math to it, then output the result to another element.

I'm running into a few problems, namely that it doesn't work.

Here's my code - http://slexy.org/view/s2TIOA5FKw.

Comment: The best thing you can do when it doesn't work is to fix the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#element_3').val()
```

When you are working with input fields, you need to use [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to retrieve their value.

**EDIT** To be clear, by "need to use" I'm saying it's better than the existing code, `var $months = $('#element_3')`. My apologies if the way I portrayed necessity was inaccurate.

---

Based on what I could piece together, this is what I came up with. I *think* this is what you're looking for. If not, I hope it's at least a step towards your solution (and helps you understand how jQuery works). Please comment on the post if you have any questions and I'll do my best to answer them.

<strike>Start off with this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/zzd3K/3/ (Working Example)

<sub>[[Commented Version]](http://www.jsfiddle.net/zzd3K/2/)</sub></strike>

[Both commented and working, with a fix to the #element_1 .bind()](http://www.jsfiddle.net/zzd3K/4/) (spelling error, "kepress" -> "keypress")

**HTML**

```
    <html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('input[name=select]').change(function(){
            $('#select').text($(this).val());
        });
        $('#element_1').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function(){
            $('#advertiserNameDisplay').html($(this).val());
        });
        $('#element_2').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function(){
            $('#adImageDisplay').text($(this).val());
        });
        $('#element_3').bind('keydown keyup keypress', calcPrice);
        function calcPrice(){
            var months = parseInt($('#element_3').val());
            if (!isNaN(months)){
                var rate = 1;
                if (months >= 1 && months < 3){
                    rate = 199;
                }else if (months >= 3 && months < 6){
                    rate = 175;
                }else{
                    rate = 150;
                }   
                var price = rate * months;
                $('#rate').text(rate);
                $('#months').text(months);
                $('#total').text(price);
            }else{
                $('#months').text('-');
            }
        }
        calcPrice();
      });
    </script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Configured Values</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Ad:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="select" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="Text" id="element_1" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ad Image URL:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="element_2" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Months:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="element_3" value="12" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <br /><br />
    <ul>
        <li>Ad Selected: #<span id="select"></span></li>
        <li>Your Name: <span id="advertiserNameDisplay"></span></li>
        <li>Your Image URL: <span id="adImageDisplay"></span></li>
        <li>Your total is $<span id="total"></span>.00 at a rate of $<span id="rate"></span>.00 per month for <span id="months"></span> months.</li>
    </ul>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

*(Don't mind the fieldset, I used it to simulate your controls)*

Comment: `this.value` is perfectly fine native JS way of getting the value of input from inside jQ function referencing to input element

Comment: @Tom: you're right, but more uniform in regards to inputs, selects, text areas, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try using parseInt, a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this
var newVal = parseInt($('#sourcElement').val());

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it's advised to start the script part at least with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

... some systems may have the script tag assigned to VBScript and your JS would therefore not work there.

Secondly, the above comments are right - you need to use **.val()** to retrieve a value, which is *probably* what you're trying to do here:

```
var $months = $('#element_3');
```

... which should read either:

```
var $months = parseInt($('#element_3').val());
// check if the value if an integer and reset it to 0 if it's not
if (isNaN($months)) {
    $months = 0;
}
```

... or:

```
var $months = $('#element_3').length;
```

(I can't say exactly, since I don't see #element_3 on the page - it can be a dropdown or a text box)

then, **line 34** contains: *$('#total').html(document.write($total))* which cannot work for 2 reasons:

1. $total is not defined anywhere in the document
2. document.write() clears the document when it has already been loaded (that's how document.write works)

you can probably get away with *$('#rate').html($rate)*

and finally, I suggest you use **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)** for debugging your code, as some of these errors would certainly show up there ;-)