# jQuery isn't updating values after doing some math

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to write a character creation assistant for a tabletop game. Depending on character level, the number of Development Points a player can invest changes. This is my first major project in html5 and jQuery, but I thought it would be simple enough. I used advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801934/jquery-math-variables), but my values aren't updating. I've been screwing around with it in jsFiddle, but to no avail. I'm at my wit's end! Here's a link to my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tasuret/9M4cD/3/).
The jsFiddle has only the relevant pieces of code that I want to work with. I got the rest of the form working.

HTML:

```
<strong>Level: </strong><input id="levelselect" type="number" min="0" max="20" />
You have <span id="DP"></span> DP to spend.
```

JS:

```
function calcDP() {
        var level = parseInt($('#levelselect').val(),10);
        var DPatZero = 400;
        var DPatOne = 600;
        var workDP = 0;

            if (level === 0){
                workDP = DPatZero;
            }
            else if(level == 1){
                workDP = DPatOne;
            }
            else {
                workDP = DPatOne + (level * 100);
            }
            var DP = workDP;

            $('#DP').text(DP);
        }

$('#levelselect').on('keydown keyup keypress', calcDP);
```

Comment: Please include the important parts of your code in the question itself. Otherwise this question will be pretty much broken when the pastebin link expires at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you were binding the selector on the wrong element. Instead of binding the events on

```
$('#DP')
```

you should be binding them to

```
$('#levelselect')
```

Second, you want to catch every event, use the event 'change' for this to make sure not only keystrokes are being caught, but pastes and pressing the up and down arrows next to the imput are being caught as well:

```
function calcDP()
{
    var level = parseInt($('#levelselect').val(), 10);
    var DPatZero = 400;
    var DPatOne = 600;
    var workDP = 0;

    if (level === 0)
    {
        workDP = DPatZero;
    }
    else if (level == 1)
    {
        workDP = DPatOne;
    }
    else
    {
        workDP = DPatOne + (level * 100);
    }

    $('#DP').text(workDP);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Bind calcDP onchange to make sure every event is being caught.
    $('#levelselect').on('change', calcDP);

    // Call the onchange event to make sure the current value is evaluated
    $('#levelselect').change();
}
```

Also, in your initial JSfiddle you used Mootools as the required framework on the left instead of jQuery.

See JS fidle for the full script: http://jsfiddle.net/9M4cD/4/

Comment: As written, that broke my other jQuery bits. By removing the `$(document).ready()` function, and leaving the `.change()` and `.on()` bits in the main body of the script, that worked. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tasuret/9M4cD/5/). Thanks for the help!

Comment: `change` is **not** enough if you want to update it while the user types!

Comment: Not while the user types, it is however getting fired as soon as the element is being blurred. Depending on your setup and whatever function gets fired by the event: choose your event type wisely.

You would not want to fire an ajax request on every single keydown, keyup and keypress.

Answer (score 2):

You bound the events to the wrong element. Use

```
$('#levelselect').on('keydown keyup keypress', calcDP);
```

instead of

```
$('#DP').on('keydown keyup keypress', calcDP);
```

and it will work.

Comment: It isn't working. I updated the question with your change, though. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Tasuret: did you test it on jsfiddle? Make sure to select jQuery as the required framework on the left, as you initially selected mootools, which indeed does not work with the code you provided.

Comment: I actually did have it set up on jQuery. It works as intended on both my local copy and the latest revision on my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tasuret/9M4cD/5/).